# create a simple dll file with JNI

Tags: java, c++, c, dll, java-native-interface

Im trying to create a simple dll file.Im following the tutorial

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html

when i try to compile the c program i get following error :

Warning W8057 HelloWorld.c 10: Parameter 'env' is never used in function Java_He
lloWorld_print
Warning W8057 HelloWorld.c 10: Parameter 'obj' is never used in function Java_He
lloWorld_print

im using Borland C++ Compiler 5.5
i used the following command to compile the c program

bcc32 -WD HelloWorld.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because most JNI functions don't need to reference the env, and some don't need to reference the object. In other words, ignore it.

Comment: yeah..i know..but the dll file isnt getting generated.

Comment: But a warning does not indicate a failure. I don't think you are passing the correct parameters to bcc32 to actually ask it to link anything.

Comment: No, I can't. I've never used Borland, and apparently neither has anyone else reading this question.